# Magento 2 form validation resetForm not working

Tags: jquery, validation, magento2

I want to reset form validation after a failed form submit.

I'm using Magneto 2 and init the form validation with data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'

```
<form ... data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'>
```

I tried to reset the errors like

```
var validator = jQuery( "#edit-product" ).validate();
validator.resetForm();
```

But it does not reset. I have a feeling Magento's data-mage-init is doing things differently the standard Jquery Validation and I have to go about resetting the form differently but so far I can's find a way that works.

Comment: have you got solution ?

Comment: No, had to go with a different solution because we could not get this one working.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested the code below and it worked for me in Magento 2,

```
$('#edit-product').validation('clearError');
```